# UWP StorageFile Efficiency

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

So reading the Microsoft Documentation it states that there are 3 methods to write to a file in UWP: the FileIO class, a buffer, or a stream. My program is performing lots of live data calculations that are time sensitive for my UI and I would like to implement a file output of this data on top of my visual display. My question is which method would be best for my program? Writing the log file is not time critical at all so which option would impact my programs operations the least?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `FileIO` class' `ReadTextAsync` and `WriteTextAsync` method should be good enough. There is no reason to use buffers unless you really have to for some reason.

Since these methods are `async` you can call them synchronously without blocking the UI during the time it takes to read or write to the file.